# Add location in kubernetes node infomation and let kubectl print it out

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to add location information in kubernetes nodes' information and let kubectl command "describe node" print out the location of the node. However, I can't print out the value of Location. 
The output is look like the image.
[output of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chrQd.png)
What did I do wrong or what should I do but I missed it?
Any help will be very much appreciated

I already added new variable

```
Location string `json:"location"`
```

in kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/info/v1/machine.go

and modified corresponding file that set and pass the value of Location.

I also added new variable

```
Location string `json:"location"`
```

in /home/william/kubernetes/pkg/api/types.go

and

```
Location string `json:"location" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=location"`
```

in /home/william/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1/types.go

I added

```
out.Location = in.Location
```

in function autoConvert_v1_NodeSystemInfo_To_api_NodeSystemInfo in /home/william/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1/zz_generated.conversion.go

```
func autoConvert_v1_NodeSystemInfo_To_api_NodeSystemInfo(in *NodeSystemInfo, out *api.NodeSystemInfo, s conversion.Scope) error {
    out.MachineID = in.MachineID
    out.SystemUUID = in.SystemUUID
    out.Location = in.Location
    out.BootID = in.BootID
    out.KernelVersion = in.KernelVersion
    out.OSImage = in.OSImage
    out.ContainerRuntimeVersion = in.ContainerRuntimeVersion
    out.KubeletVersion = in.KubeletVersion
    out.KubeProxyVersion = in.KubeProxyVersion
    out.OperatingSystem = in.OperatingSystem
    out.Architecture = in.Architecture
    return nil
}
```

and add

```
fmt.Fprintf(out, " Location:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.Location)
```

in function describeNode in /home/william/kubernetes/pkg/kubectl/describe.go

```
func describeNode(node *api.Node, nodeNonTerminatedPodsList *api.PodList, events *api.EventList, canViewPods bool) (string, error) {
return tabbedString(func(out io.Writer) error {
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "Name:\t%s\n", node.Name)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "Role:\t%s\n", findNodeRole(node))
    printLabelsMultiline(out, "Labels", node.Labels)
    printTaintsInAnnotationMultiline(out, "Taints", node.Annotations)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "CreationTimestamp:\t%s\n", node.CreationTimestamp.Time.Format(time.RFC1123Z))
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "Phase:\t%v\n", node.Status.Phase)
    if len(node.Status.Conditions) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprint(out, "Conditions:\n  Type\tStatus\tLastHeartbeatTime\tLastTransitionTime\tReason\tMessage\n")
        fmt.Fprint(out, "  ----\t------\t-----------------\t------------------\t------\t-------\n")
        for _, c := range node.Status.Conditions {
            fmt.Fprintf(out, "  %v \t%v \t%s \t%s \t%v \t%v\n",
                c.Type,
                c.Status,
                c.LastHeartbeatTime.Time.Format(time.RFC1123Z),
                c.LastTransitionTime.Time.Format(time.RFC1123Z),
                c.Reason,
                c.Message)
        }
    }
    addresses := make([]string, 0, len(node.Status.Addresses))
    for _, address := range node.Status.Addresses {
        addresses = append(addresses, address.Address)
    }

    printResourceList := func(resourceList api.ResourceList) {
        resources := make([]api.ResourceName, 0, len(resourceList))
        for resource := range resourceList {
            resources = append(resources, resource)
        }
        sort.Sort(SortableResourceNames(resources))
        for _, resource := range resources {
            value := resourceList[resource]
            fmt.Fprintf(out, " %s:\t%s\n", resource, value.String())
        }
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(out, "Addresses:\t%s\n", strings.Join(addresses, ","))
    if len(node.Status.Capacity) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "Capacity:\n")
        printResourceList(node.Status.Capacity)
    }
    if len(node.Status.Allocatable) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "Allocatable:\n")
        printResourceList(node.Status.Allocatable)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(out, "System Info:\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Machine ID:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.MachineID)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " System UUID:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.SystemUUID)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Location:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.Location)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Boot ID:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.BootID)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Kernel Version:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.KernelVersion)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " OS Image:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.OSImage)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Operating System:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.OperatingSystem)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Architecture:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.Architecture)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Container Runtime Version:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.ContainerRuntimeVersion)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Kubelet Version:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.KubeletVersion)
    fmt.Fprintf(out, " Kube-Proxy Version:\t%s\n", node.Status.NodeInfo.KubeProxyVersion)

    if len(node.Spec.PodCIDR) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "PodCIDR:\t%s\n", node.Spec.PodCIDR)
    }
    if len(node.Spec.ExternalID) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "ExternalID:\t%s\n", node.Spec.ExternalID)
    }
    if canViewPods && nodeNonTerminatedPodsList != nil {
        if err := describeNodeResource(nodeNonTerminatedPodsList, node, out); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "Pods:\tnot authorized\n")
    }
    if events != nil {
        DescribeEvents(events, out)
    }
    return nil
})
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is not the answer you are hoping for but why not just add a label `location=x` and use `kubectl get node -L location` ?

Comment: Like the comment before me, your use case is why there's node labels. You can label your nodes and the labels will be shown also when you to `kubectl describe node`. Adding the location in code, would have you add it each time there's a new version of k8s out, as this kind of change won't get merged upstream. If you look at how cloud nodes are automatically labeled in k8s cloud-provider the labels also include location/region

Comment: It's because devices in this cluster may move at any time, so I want to read the GPS on devices and update the location value automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a program that runs on each node which reads the nodes location and then updates the node's label or (annotation) in the kubernetes node API.

You don't need to modify the kubernetes source to accomplish this.  If you modify the kubernetes source, it will be harder to pickup future changes and you won't be able to use standard releases..

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: You may wish to accept this answer if it was useful